# Analytical distribution of sum of realization of uniform distributions with/without discount

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, summation, expected-value

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable that can take value in (knwon) $x=[x_1, ..., x_n]$ uniformly.

Is there an analytical PDF/CDF of the random variable $Y$ defined by the sum of $N$ realization of $X$ with and without replacement?

My objective is to compute analytically the standard deviation, mean and quantiles of $Y$ with respect to $X$ and its own statistical characteristics.

Right now I bascicaly make Monte Carlo simulation to make the N successive draws and sum them, but I was wondering if an analytical formulation would exist.

I saw that the binomial and hypergeometric distribution respectively describe the probability of k successes with and without replacement but it seems that it's not what I am looking for.

Any idea?